# "Not Found" error for all other routes except for / using laravel 5.1 on a EC2 instance AWS

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, laravel-5.1

Trying to set up a laravel 5.1 project on EC2 (aws). I've so far installed a LAMP stack (php 5.6) and composer. It all seems to be working fine. Was even able to run migrations for the laravel app, But whenever I try to go to any route except '/' I get a

```
Not Found

The requested URL /public/pricing was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at compute.amazonaws.com   Port 80
```

error.

Not sure whats going on. It works perfectly fine on my localhost using mamp.

Comment: Sounds like a `mod_rewrite` issue. Have you checked your .htaccess file?

Comment: @kevinabraham: Have you found any solution for this? I'm hosting on linode server and facing the same problem. If you found the solution, please help... Thanks in advance

Comment: @JTheDev I can see you found a solution in the comment below. 

Answer (score 3):

Three things to consider;
1) you should set the document root to public not the Laravel directory. In simpler words, users should be be able to access the Laravel directory.

2) check out your Apache find files or .htaccess to allow for override

```
AllowOverride All
```

3) Make sure mode_rewrite is enabled

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had already enabled rewrite and done the AllowOverride and restarted apache. For some reason nothing worked. I closed the connection to the server and rebooted and it all started working. No idea why.

Comment: Yep. I completed all the steps to resolve the issue. Maybe for some reason apache wouldnt restart and rebooting the server, Reset apache.

Comment: I think, I found the solution. For me it was the problem with AllowOverride All.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds/looks like you are missing the htaccess file:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#configuration

If you navigate to /public/index.php?pricing, the webpage will most likely show up even now.

You will need to configure the .htaccess file to pass requests to index.php to handle the routing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had already set up the htaccess file using laravel configuration and restarted apache. For some reason nothing worked. I closed the connection to the server and rebooted and it all started working. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled mod rewrite

Set up htaccess

AllowOverride All

It didn't change anything. I then killed the connection to the server and rebooted and everything was working. Not exactly sure why this worked but fortunately it did.